# Return of memory at the termination of a C++ program

Tags: c++, memory

When a C++ program terminates, the RAM used during the run gets cleaned and is returned to the system, correct?

Question 1)
Is this memory returned managed by C++ language features or by the computer hardware itself?

Question 2)
Does the memory get returned efficiently/safely, if I terminate a run using `ctrl+Z` in Unix terminal?

Comment: Ctrl-Z does not usually terminate a process.

Comment: I mentioned that in my answer, as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When a C++ program terminates, the RAM used during the run gets cleaned and is returned to the system, correct?

Correct. By System, I hope you mean, Operating System.

> Question 1) Is this memory *returned managed* by C++ language features or by the computer hardware itself?

The *returned* memory is *managed* by the operating system <sup>(if I correctly understand the question).</sup> And before returning to the OS, the memory is managed by the process; in low-level, which means, managed by various language features, such as allocation- deallocation mechanism, constructors, destructors, [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization), etc.

> Question 2) Does the memory get returned efficiently/safely, if I terminate a run using ctrl+Z in Unix terminal?

Ctrl+Z *suspends* the process. It doesn't terminate it. So the memory doesn't get returned to the OS as long as the process is not terminated.

In linux, Ctrl+C terminates the process, then the memory returns to the OS.

Comment: Yes I meant the operating system. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: This might be a stupid follow up question, but suppose if I press `ctrl + z` which would suspend the process as you say. Now if I switch of my computer will that suspended memory be returned/cleaned during shut down?

Comment: If you switch off your computer, all of its (physical) memory will be "cleaned!"

Answer (score 5):

1. Typically both. At least assuming normal termination, destructors will run, which will typically free the memory associated with those objects. Once your program exits, the OS will free all the memory that was owned by that process.
2. A forced termination often won't run the destructors and such, but any reasonable operating system is going to clean up after a process terminates, whether it did so cleanly or not. There are limits though, so if you've used things like lock files, it probably can't clean those up.

Answer (score 3):

> Q: When a C++ program terminates, the RAM used during the run gets
>   cleaned and is returned to the system, correct?

A: Correct.  This is true for ANY program, regardless of the language it was written in, and regardless of whether it's Linux, Windows or another OS

> Q Is this memory returned managed by C++ language features or by the
>   computer hardware itself?

A: Neither: the operating system is responsible for managing a process's memory.

> Q: Does the memory get returned efficiently/safely, if I terminate a
>   run using ctrl+Z in Unix terminal?

A: OS resources (such as memory) are freed.  But you can leave files corrupted, IPCs locked, and other Bad Things that are beyond the OS's control if you kill a program gracelessly.

'Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

> Is this memory returned managed by C++ language features or by the computer hardware itself?

Both occur, assuming a proper shutdown (vs. a crash or kill). The standard C/C++ library deallocates any (non-leaked) memory it allocated via OS system calls and ultimately the OS cleans up any leaked memory.

> Does the memory get returned efficiently/safely, if I terminate a run using ctrl+Z in Unix terminal?

Ctrl-Z suspends a process on Unix. If you terminate it using kill or kill -9, the memory will be reclaimed (safely / efficiently) by the OS.

Comment: And the lesser known `kill -2` and `kill -3`. Memory will be reclaimed, independent of termination method.

Comment: I don't know of a c++ runtime that returns RAM to the OS.  Usually once a c++ process has touched a page of RAM it retains it for the life of the process.

Comment: @deft_code, I agree with what you are saying while the process is running, but that does not preclude stdlib from returning all memory pages back to the OS during graceful termination.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that it is stdlib that returns the memory during shutdown.  I would think it is the OS after the process exits the reaps all the memory, but I'm not 100% sure. In general, unless you have changed the behavior via mallopt(), I think I agree with deft_code that no memory is returned by stdlib.  I can't say I have ever really actually verified this, though.

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn: my point was that stdlib doesn't return the memory pages to the OS.  It can be done (I think the JVM does that after compaction).  The OS reclaims memory pages after the process has stopped executing, the stdlib has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score -1):

They say that dynamically allocated memory is only returned by you, the programmer. For example, a

```
myclass *obj = new myclass();
```

always has to have a corresponding

```
delete obj;
```

somwehere, or else your program will leak memory, meaning the operating system could think that certain parts of memory are used when in fact they are not - after too many leaks your memory might be used up by false memory entirely and you won't be able to do anything with it.

However, "C++" (effectively meaning "the compiler") takes care of everything that you allocate on the stack, like

```
myclass obj;
```

as long as  your destructors actually correctly deletes anything which you dynamically create inside that class.

In practice however, if you leak memory, modern operating systems will take care of it and usually clean it up. Usually there's some system in place where the OS will be able to recognize what parts of the memory you actually used, and then simply free everything in there as soon as the application is terminated.

Memory leaks usually only really create problems when your application needs so much memory that it needs to correctly free up some from time to time, or when you continuously leak memory in a loop (like in games), on systems with limited memory (like consoles).

Comment: Sorry - your statement that "modern operating systems will take care of it" is completely wrong.  Memory leaks remain a VERY real pitfall.  That's why garbage-collecting environments like the Java runtime or .Net are so popular - because they help mitigate the problem.